# How to group by HashMap?

Tags: kotlin, hashmap

I have next variable:

```
private var consents: Map<ConnectionID, List<ConsentData>> = emptyMap()
```

And after in my function i do next actions:

```
fun processDecryptedConsentsResult(result: List<ConsentData>) {
        this.consents = result.groupBy { it.connectionId ?: "" }
        ...
}
```

And everything works ok.

But now i changed my variable to:

```
private var consents: HashMap<ConnectionID, List<ConsentData>> = HashMap<ConnectionID, List<ConsentData>>()
```

And can't groupBy, because

```
Required: collections HashMap<ConnectionID /*=String*/, List<ConsentData>>
Found: Map<String. List<ConsentData>>
```

How i can groupBy my HashMap now?

Comment: What do you mean by `ConnectionID /*=String*/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `groupBy` returns a `Map<K, List<T>>`, you cannot directly assign that to a HashMap field/property.

You can however initialize the HashMap by passing the Map as below:

```
this.consents = HashMap(result.groupBy { it.connectionId ?: "" })
```